# Determine Alphabetic Order of Two Characters using if else statement in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

Determine Alphabetic Order of Two Characters using if else statement in Java, without using the following code

```
return Character.toLowerCase(ch1) < Character.toLowerCase(ch2);
```

Comment: Convert to ascii

Comment: Something cryptic like `return (ch1 & 31) < (ch2 & 31);` or circumstantial like `Character.toString(ch1).compareIgnoreCase(Character.toString(ch2)) < 0`. It would be good to know more about the expectations.

Comment: `return Character.toUppeerCase(ch1) < Character.toUpperCase(ch2);` ? not using toLowerCase...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way

```
Character a = 'w';
Character b = 'Z';
return (a-b>0) ? "a > b" : (a-b==0) ? "a == b" : "a < b";
```